# Annihilator of a finitely presented module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Suppose $M$ is a finitely presented $R$-module i.e. there is a short exact sequence
$$
R^m \to R^n \to M \to 0.
$$
Is it true that the annihilator ${\rm Ann}_R(M)=\{x\in R \mid xm=0 \text{ for all } m \in M\}$ is a finitely generated ideal?

Comment: All I can say for now is that $\sqrt{\mathrm{Ann}(M)}=\sqrt I$, with $I$ a finitely generated ideal.

Comment: Sure, where $I$ is the ideal generated by $n \times n$ minors of the presentation matrix (zeroth Fitting ideal). But radical of a finitely generated ideal is not necessarily finitely generated and converse is also false.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a motivation for the question. Otherwise it remains as a curiosity, and nothing more.

Comment: For me this is indeed a curiosity. I noticed that if $I={\rm Ann}M$, for a flat module $M$, then $R/I$ is flat, hence $I=I^2$. If I suppose $M$ is also finitely presented, then $M$ is projective and it is well-known that support of $M$ is clopen. If what I'm asking is true, then I get another proof of that fact, by noticing that if $I$ is finite and $I=I^2$, then $I$ generated by an idempotent. But I stuck with the property in question, can't prove it or find a counter-example.

Comment: How do you show that $R/I$ is a flat $R-$module?

Comment: By localizing at primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no.  For domains, this happens for all f.p. modules precisely when $R$ is coherent.  In general I suspect it is a subtle property.

Consider the following three conditions:

$(i)$ Intersections of finitely generated $R$-submodules of free $R$-modules are finitely generated.

$(ii)$ Annihilators of finitely presented $R$-modules are finitely generated.

$(iii)$ Intersections of finitely generated ideals of $R$ are finitely generated.

We check that $(i) \implies (ii) \implies (iii)$.

To see that $(i) \implies (ii)$, consider $M$ finitely presented and $0 \rightarrow K \subseteq A^n \twoheadrightarrow M \rightarrow 0$.  Let $F_i$ denote the free submodule of $A^n$ generated by the $i$th coefficient.  By assumption, $F_i \cap K$ is finitely generated, and since it is a submodule of $F_i$, which is naturally identified with $R$, we see that $F_i \cap K$ is naturally identified with a finitely generated ideal $I_i$.  Moreover, $(K :_R F_i) = I_i$, and therefore $\operatorname{Ann}(M) = (K :_R R^n) = \bigcap I_i$ is finitely generated.

To see $(ii) \implies (iii)$, let $I, J$ be two finitely generated ideals.  Set $M = R/I \oplus R/J$.  Clearly $M$ is finitely presented and $\operatorname{Ann}(M) = I \cap J$.

Additional notes:  if $M$ is a coherent module, then its annihilator is clearly finitely presented.  Indeed, each generator $m_i$ generates a cyclic finitely presented module (even a coherent module).  Then the canonical map $R \rightarrow \bigoplus m_iR$ sending $1$ to $(m_1, \ldots, m_n)$ is a homomorphism from a finite module to a coherent module, and therefore its kernel is finitely generated.[[Stacks 05CW]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05CU).  But the kernel of this map is just the $R$-annihilator of $M$.

In particular, if $R$ is a coherent ring, then $(ii)$ holds.

Recall that a ring is coherent iff (1) annihilators of finitely generated ideals are finitely generated and (2) intersections of finitely generated ideals are finitely generated.  In particular, a domain is coherent iff $(2)$ holds.

Furthermore, if $R$ is any ring in which $R$-elements have finitely generated annihilators, then $(ii)$ holds in $R$ iff $R$ is coherent.  In particular, this is true for a domain.

In general, I'm not sure how coherence and $(ii)$ are related.  Generalized valuation rings always satisfy the property, regardless of coherence.  See [[Stacks 0ASP]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ASP)